# Help recreating a gradient

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I need to recreate this gradient, but I'm not very good with gradients. Any tips? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Make two rectangles: blue behind and the green in front
- Select the green rectangle and fill it with a gradient form green to the same blue as the big rectangle, angle 60º
- Apply a Feather effect to the green rectangle

[image: rectangles]

- Go to menu **View** > **Show Gradient Annotator**
- Change the gradient to Radial
- Select the **Gradient Tool** move the gradient center and adjust scaling the radius and diameter

[image: gradient]

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to merely use a **Gradient Mesh**.

- Draw a rectangle and fill it with the blue.
- Grab the **Gradient Mesh Tool** and then click one of the *corner* anchors on the rectangle. This converts the rectangle to a Mesh object *without* adding any additional Mesh points.
- Click again with the **Gradient Mesh Tool** where you want the green to be centered.
- Then select the green color from swatches (Or adjust the color panel to apply the green.)

[image]

This method typically does a better job of color fades between colors and allows for the curved or arched open ended green toward the top right.